# Grails 3 - Use SQL Server Geography type?

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

How can I use the SQL Server Geography type? Or is there documentation on using custom database types? I'm looking for integration with Grails/GORM.

Answer (score 0):

A. Showing how to add and query geography data:

The following examples show how to add and query geography data. The first example creates a table with an identity column and a geography column, GeogCol1. A third column renders the geography column into its Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) Well-Known Text (WKT) representation, and uses the STAsText() method. Two rows are then inserted: one row contains a LineString instance of geography, and one row contains a Polygon instance.

```
    CREATE TABLE SpatialTable   
        ( id int IDENTITY (1,1),  
        GeogCol1 geography,   
        GeogCol2 AS GeogCol1.STAsText() );  
    GO 



INSERT INTO SpatialTable (GeogCol1)  
VALUES (geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(-122.360 47.656, -122.343 47.656 )', 4326));  

INSERT INTO SpatialTable (GeogCol1)  
VALUES (geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-122.358 47.653 , -122.348 47.649, -122.348 47.658, -122.358 47.658, -122.358 47.653))', 4326));  
GO
```

B. Returning the intersection of two geography instances:

The following example uses the STIntersection() method to return the points where the two previously inserted geography instances intersect.

```
DECLARE @geog1 geography;  
DECLARE @geog2 geography;  
DECLARE @result geography;  

SELECT @geog1 = GeogCol1 FROM SpatialTable WHERE id = 1;  
SELECT @geog2 = GeogCol1 FROM SpatialTable WHERE id = 2;  
SELECT @result = @geog1.STIntersection(@geog2);  
SELECT @result.STAsText();
```

Comment: I'm looking for integration with Grails/GORM. I'll update the question to clarify.

Comment: Unfortunately, hibernate-spatial does not support the geography type (http://www.hibernatespatial.org/documentation/03-dialects/06-mssqlserver/). I'm going to need to make a custom type.